# Keep Outlook mailItem property (internet header) from being removed when forwarded/replied

Tags: header, outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-2010, mailitem

I'm trying to start up a thread of mails defined by the same ID (ID needs to be a specific value equal to the one in our database). I can assign a custom internet header just fine like this:

```
sendMail.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string/{00020386-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/DCPID", taskId);
```

Where the sendMail is an `olMailItem` and `taskId` is the id needed.

When this mail is sent and recieved I can get my ID with the `GetProperty` method but when forwarded or replied the internet header gets removed and I can't access this property anymore.

**Is there a way to keep your custom internet header from being removed, no matter where it goes?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to preserve a custom message header on reply or forward.